# Is there a way to order the WHERE conditions that my JPQL query tries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a query

```
SELECT CAST(p.propertyId AS long) FROM Property p
 WHERE p.propertyId IS NOT NULL
   AND p.propertyId NOT LIKE '%-%'
   AND p.propertyId NOT LIKE '%+%'
```

That works beautifully because the WHERE conditions successfully filter out all of the non-numeric values for propertyId. But if I try to use the cast *as* a condition

```
SELECT p FROM Property p
 WHERE p.propertyId IS NOT NULL
   AND p.propertyId NOT LIKE '%-%'
   AND p.propertyId NOT LIKE '%+%'
   AND CAST(p.propertyId AS long) BETWEEN 999999 AND 10000000
```

it fails with the error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number`.

Is there a way to force the last condition to only check of the first three pass?

Comment: so what values do you get back that should be showing up, and what are they before/after the casting?

Comment: In the first query I get longs back. If I don't cast them they come back as strings. In the second query I don't get anything as it fails.

Comment: Did you check the resulting SQL? It's not the JPQL query but the SQL query it is translated into that causes the problem (hint: you get a SQLException).

Comment: Did you try to use parantheses to define the evaluation order?

Comment: They're all AND conditions. Where would I put parentheses to order some of them first

Comment: Resulting SQL is pretty much the same thing. Looks like `select property0_ as col_0_0_ from SCH.Property property0_
 where (property0_.PROPERTY_ID is not null)
 and (property0_.PROPERTY_ID not like '%-%')
 and (property0_.PROPERTY_ID not like '%+%')
 and (cast(property0_.PROPERTY_ID as number(19,0)) between 999999 and 10000000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 1st request filters out all non numeric values you can select from its result:

```
SELECT p FROM
(
SELECT p1 FROM Property p1
 WHERE p1.propertyId IS NOT NULL
   AND p1.propertyId NOT LIKE '%-%'
   AND p1.propertyId NOT LIKE '%+%'
)
where CAST(p.propertyId AS long) BETWEEN 999999 AND 10000000
```

Comment: You can't do JPQL subqueries in the FROM clause, but that's good thinking. I can probably do something with EXISTS